# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred Xcode 11 iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I am getting "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" for the following code after updating to Xcode 11. Earlier it use to work fine.

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func register<T>(_ anyClass : T.Type) where T:UICollectionViewCell {
        register(anyClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: String.stringFromClass(anyClass))
    }

    func registerCells<T>(_ cells: [T.Type]) where T:UICollectionViewCell{
        for cellClass in cells{
            self.register(cellClass)
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the error while registering cells -

```
collectionView.registerCells([CarouselSmallVideoCell.self, CarouselSmallArticleCell.self])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `register` or `registerCells` to be generic:

```
func register(_ anyClass : UICollectionViewCell.Type) {
    print("\(anyClass.self)")
}

func registerCells(_ cells: [UICollectionViewCell.Type]) {
    for cellClass in cells{
        register(cellClass)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` needs to be derived from a singular type. I think Apple has enforced their compiler type-checking mechanisms more in XCode 11.

To expound:

It is ambiguous for the compiler to confidently infer the type listed here:

`collectionView.registerCells([CarouselSmallVideoCell.self, CarouselSmallArticleCell.self])`

The compiler has to check if `T` is of type `CarouselSmallVideoCell` or `CarouselSmallArticleCell`; they are not of the same type.

What instead you can do is change your function signature from:

`func registerCells<T>(_ cells: [T.Type]) where T:UICollectionViewCell`

To:

`func registerCells(_ cells: [UICollectionViewCell.Type])`

Answer (score 0):

Type inference has apparently become dumber. Put the array into a variable first:

```swift
let cells = [CarouselSmallVideoCell.self, CarouselSmallArticleCell.self]
collectionView.registerCells(cells)
```